# Too many input arguments in MATLAB while writing to excel

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a `for` loop for `i` and I used

```
xlswrite('regression.xls', i, 'R', ['A' num2str(count)]);
```

to write in excel.
But if I want to use two `for` loops  `i` and `j`,
and I want to write them in same cell in excel like `i_j`

```
xlswrite('regression.xls', i_j, 'R', ['A' num2str(count)]);
```

it shows too many input arguments. So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's what you are asking for but try to replace `i_j` by `[num2str(i) '_' num2str(j)]`.

Comment: Its writing only i_    but not i_j.
suppose
>>for  i=4:5                                                        
  for j=5:6;
      xlswrite('regression.xls', [num2str(i)_num2str(j)], 'R', ['A' num2str(count)]);
  end
end

it should write
4_5
4_6
5_5
5_6

Comment: You mean `>> for i=4:5 for j=5:6; xlswrite('regression.xls', [num2str(i) '_' num2str(j)], 'R', ['A' num2str(count)]); end end` and yes, that was my understanding. I also suppose you increment `count` somewhere in your loop. Does it work?

Comment: No Sir.. its writing the i value in A column and _ in the B column . and there is no j value

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that rather than writing each result to excel in the for loop, you construct an array in the loop, and write that in one go after the loop.

Somthing like

```
idx=0
for i=4:5;
  for j=5:6;
    arr(idx) = [num2str(i) '_' num2str(j)];
    idx++;
  end
end
xlswrite('regression.xls', arr, 'R', "A1");
```

Note:

1. you probably could do this without the for loops with some matrix operations
2. code is un-tested!